# sas summing a third variable in a proc freq

Tags: sas, sum, frequency

I want to create a table like below from `proc freq` or `proc tabulate` or something similar from my dataset where I have three variables: `andel` (share), `Aar` (year) and `Gruppe` (group).

In my dataset I have about 500-thousand observations, where 1 observation represents a person.

How do I create the table without having to programme my way through lots of datasets?

I have tried:

```
proc freq data= data;
Tables Aar*gruppe*andel / nopercent norow nocol nocum ;
run;
```

and

```
proc tabulate data= data  missing;
class  gruppe aar andel  ;
Table  aar*gruppe*andel   , all/ rts=180;
run;
```

But none of this work - and it's because I want the shares (the variable `andel`) to be summed and not counted for each group `gruppe` and year `aar`. AND I DON'T want a table for each year (6 tables) of the summed `andel` for each `gruppe`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Proc Tabulate is probably the right place to go.  It has the concept of `class` versus `var`.  `Class` is something to group things by; `var` is something to do computations on (sum, mean, etc.)

```
proc tabulate data= data  missing;
class  gruppe aar ;
var andel;
Table  gruppe,aar*andel*sum/ rts=180;
run;
```

Something like that should be your starting point.  Comma separates row from column from table; rightmost is column, second-rightmost is row, third-rightmost is page (leftmost).  Star combines elements; here, this says

> Create a table where rows are groups and columns are years, and for
>   each year/group combination, display the sum of shares.

The *andel*sum could go either after gruppe or after aar, it largely doesn't matter (there are some times it may make a difference, and traditionally it's placed after the column variable when it doesn't matter, but in this case it would be the same), except for where the label goes that indicates what the analytic variable is (if you want it - you can remove it).

Comment: HiThanks for your sugestion. I've tried your code, but SAS gave me this error: ERROR: The type of name (andel) is unknown. AFterwards I added "andel" in the class statement and then SAS give me this error: ERROR: Statistic other than N was requested without analysis variable in the following nesting : gruppe * aar * andel * Sum. I'm not yet so good at understanding the log - any suggestions??

Comment: HALLELUJA - now it works. The syntax is: proc tabulate data= data  missing;
var   andel;
class  gruppe aar ;
Table  gruppe,aar*andel / rts=180;
run;

Comment: Ah, yes.  I missed the VAR statement, sorry!